# Eloquent ORM - access to eager-loaded columns

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I think I'm running myself in circles here, so I'm hoping to get some help - I should say that I have very little experience with PHP/laravel/eloquent, this is an inherited project.

I have a many-to-many relationship between two classes [Ticket and Comment]. I then have a many-to-one relationship between [Comment and User]. Authors on a Ticket are defined as the distinct set of users who have comments on the ticket.

I would like to eager load author IDs when retrieving tickets (I don't need the whole user, just the id)

Originally authors was given by `$this->hasMany(Comments::class)->select('author_id)->distinct()`

Which is fine when only retrieving them for a single ticket but will be slow when doing it for all tickets. Attempting to eager load this, even with a foreign key will fail because the ORM can't convert it to a valid SQL statement (I don't think?)

So I though I would define authors based on the comments for a ticket and eager load the comments, then theoretically I can get the distinct authors without having to go back to the database every time:

```
function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}

function authors()
{
   return ($this->comments == null 
        ? $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->select('author_id')->distinct() 
        : $this->comments->select('author_id')->distinct()); 
}
```

I figured then that if I call:

```
$tickets = Tickets::with('comments')->get();
```

Then the authors can be determined in memory, but I think lacking a fundamental understanding of what is going on behind the scenes is causing me issues here, as this doesn't work. I suspect I'm approaching this in completely the wrong manner and would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction!

Comment: why are you testing for this `$this->comments == null`?

Comment: Ah, that's just where I ended when I gave up - on the theory that if comments had been loaded I wanted to use what was in memory, and if not it was fine to go off to the DB to get them - again it's likely I'm misunderstanding how exactly the ORM works.